# Edit an Model and post it to Controller

Tags: asp.net, view, model

I've got a model which has 10 different properties, I want to edit data in a grid now when I click on "edit" in a row it opens me an modal edit window.
But how can I pass the edited model to the action not only the 2 properties

```
public class Bestellungen
{
    public virtual int BID { get; set; }
    public virtual int UID { get; set; }
    public virtual int PID { get; set; }
    public virtual int Shop_SID { get; set; }
    public virtual string er { get; set; }
    public virtual string cker { get; set; }
    public virtual float ten { get; set; }
    public virtual float en { get; set; }
    public virtual Boolean ueck { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Datum { get; set; }
}
```

In my Partial View Form ill edit 2 of these properties:

```
        <form id="FormId" style="padding: 20px">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="form-cker">cker</label>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.cker, new { @cols = "40", @rows = "3", @id = "form-cker" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="form-er">er</label>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.er, new { @cols = "40", @rows = "3", @id = "er" })
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="approve-btn" class="btn btn-danger">          save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">      canncel</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#approve-btn").on("click", function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/edit",
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#FormId').serialize()
            })
            .done(function (partialViewResult) {
                $("#partial").html(partialViewResult);
                $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can merge serialized "big" form with `data: $('#FormId').serialize()`. But it is not beautiful solution. It is a crutch. The good idea is creating another action in controller which saves only this two fields. How about doing this?

Comment: Look, if you add some new logic to "Home/Edit" action about saving other fields, you can get problems with saving these two fields. It is very bad situation. I really suggest you add another action.

Comment: But how can i hold my other properties like PID, UID if i send only those 2 fields?

Comment: Is this model stored in database? You can only send ID (from big form, I guess) to action. But not all fields.

Comment: yes its stored in databse and i update it with Nhibernate in the Controller